How do I embed and run cx_Freeze entirely within a script without requiring CLI arguments?
I'm working on an exe-builder script that simplifies and expands on cx_Freeze, however I cannot find any information on how to embed and run cx_Freeze entirely within a script without needing CLI arguments.
The documentation states that this can be done, but doesn't explain how or give any examples.
From the cx_Freeze overview:

There are three different ways to use cx_Freeze:

Use the included cxfreeze script.

Create a setup script. This is useful if you need extra options when freezing your program because you can save them in the script. Run cxfreeze-quickstart to generate a simple setup script.

Work directly with the classes and modules used internally by cx_Freeze. This should be reserved for complicated scripts or extending or embedding.



I believe I just need to expand upon a standard setup.py cx_Freeze script, as they can be run on their own without the need for cxfreeze.exe. However those scripts require a CLI command to actually do anything, and I cannot work out how to implement that into the script itself.
I've tried digging around in the setup class but it's not obvious where it's reading the CLI arguments.
Any help would be much appreciated!
